# Javascript String replace for '&' not working

Tags: javascript

Code as below

```
var data = '<address>Test String & Test</address>';
var cleanData = data.replace('/&/g', "and");
```

I would like to replace all occurrences of '&'

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d33wyw6g/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the quotes from the regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a regex, do not place it between quotes, you can use it directly:

```
var data = '<address>Test String & Test</address>';
var cleanData = data.replace(/&/g, "and");
```

This will replace all "&" and not only the first one

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/d33wyw6g/2/

Answer (score 2):

try `var cleanData = data.replace(/&/g, "and");`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d33wyw6g/3/)

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
data.replace("&", "and");
```

Comment: this will only replace single occurrence